# How to get EditTemplateItem in ASPxGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using `ASPxUploadControl` inside `EditItemTemplate` in `ASPxGridView`. When I click on edit row button the `ASPxUploadControl` is shown, if not in edit mode it acts as a hyperlink column and show the download file option. The issue I'm facing is that I'm not getting the control object in the Insertion and Updation event of `ASPxGridView`.

I' doing something like this

```
ASPxUploadControl = grid.FindEditRowCellTemplate(grid.Columns[0] as GridViewDataColumn, "upload_control_id") as ASPxUploadControl;
```

I've also tried `grid.FindControl()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Edit [Refer This](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxUploadControlASPxUploadControl_UploadedFilestopic)

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FilesUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FilesUploadCompleteEventArgs e){
    // Intentionally pauses server-side processing to demonstrate the Loading Panel or Progress Panel functionality
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

    ASPxUploadControl uploadControl = sender as ASPxUploadControl;

    if (uploadControl.UploadedFiles != null && uploadControl.UploadedFiles.Length > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadControl.UploadedFiles.Length; i++){
            UploadedFile file = uploadControl.UploadedFiles[i];
            if (file.FileName != ""){
                string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", MapPath("~/Images/"), file.FileName);
                //file.SaveAs(fileName, true);//OnLine Demo Restriction
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Update or Insert event, get the GridView to find the get it's template control.

```
ASPxGridView gridView = sender as ASPxGridView;
ASPxUploadControl control = gridView.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(gridView.Columns[0] as GridViewDataColumn, "upload_control_id") as ASPxUploadControl;
```

**References:**
[find control update edititemtemplate](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q257328)
[ASPxGridView - How to find a control inside the EditItemTemplate](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q344248)
[ASPxGridView - How to find a control in EditItemTemplate](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q340644)
[How to programmatically reach any AspxControl inside an AspXGridView's EditItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266282/how-to-programmatically-reach-any-aspxcontrol-inside-an-aspxgridviews-edititemt)
[ASPxGridView Find control (Checkbox) and Check if it is checked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602978/aspxgridview-find-control-checkbox-and-check-if-it-is-checked-or-not)

example code snippet:

```
Protected Sub grid_RowInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs) Handles grdProyectos.RowInserting
        Dim grid As ASPxGridView = (TryCast(sender, ASPxGridView))
        Dim chk As CheckBox= grid.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(grid.Columns("name_colum"), "nameCheckBox")
        Dim marcada as Boolean = chk.Checked
End Sub
```